# Moq - How to setup a Lazy interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I want to mock a Lazy Interface and also `Setup` a method to return false.

The problem is, when i run the test, I get a NotSupportedException:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: mock => mock.Value

Here is a simplified example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    var someService = new Mock<Lazy<IService>>();

    /*this line throws the exception*/  
    someService.Setup(x => x.Value.SomeMethod()).Returns(false);
    ...
}
```

Please consider that `SomeMethod` is actually virtual, but somehow getting the lazy initialization using `x.Value` is not supported by Moq.

I didn't found a solution for this specific scenario but I did view some other approaches on declarations, but sadly didn't work for me.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    var someService = new Mock<IService>();
    var lazySomeService = new Lazy<IService>(() => someService.Object);

    //tried this but won't compile
    //lazySomeService.Setup(x => x.Value.SomeMethod()).Returns(false);
    //lazySomeService.Value.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod()).Returns(false);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You started on the right track with

```
var someService = new Mock<IService>();
var lazySomeService = new Lazy<IService>(() => someService.Object);
```

but the setup needs to be on the mock not the actual `Lazy` implementation.

```
someService.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod()).Returns(false);
```

That way when the `Lazy.Value` is called, it will be using the mock.